# How to make sidebar for this?

Tags: jquery, html, sidebar

I'm trying to fix sidebar and make it appear and disappear on click.

Can you please help me out ! ! !

Here is HTML code:

```
        <div id="left">     <div class="moduletable">
                            <div class=" modtit">По материалу</div>
                        <ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-118"><a href="/metallicheskie-dveri.html" >Металлические двери</a></li><li class="item-119"><a href="/derevyannye-dveri.html" >Клееный брус</a></li><li class="item-121"><a href="/plastikovye-dveri.html" >Пластиковые двери</a></li><li class="item-122"><a href="/shponirovannye-dveri.html" >Шпонированные двери</a></li><li class="item-157"><a href="/massiv-drevesiny.html" >Массив древесины</a></li></ul>
        </div>
            <div class="moduletable">
                            <div class=" modtit">Фурнитура</div>
                        <ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-163"><a href="/catalog-ruchek.html" >Каталог дверных ручек</a></li><li class="item-164"><a href="/zamki.html" >Замки и защелки</a></li><li class="item-165"><a href="/koroba.html" >Наличники и короба</a></li><li class="item-166"><a href="/arki.html" >Арки</a></li><li class="item-167"><a href="/lestnitsy.html" >Лестницы</a></li></ul>
        </div>
            <div class="moduletable diz">
                            <div class=" modtit">По дизайну</div>
                        <ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-136"><a href="/barokko.html" >Барокко</a></li><li class="item-137"><a href="/klassika.html" >Классика</a></li><li class="item-158"><a href="/ampir.html" >Ампир</a></li><li class="item-159"><a href="/minimalizm.html" >Минимализм</a></li><li class="item-160"><a href="/pop-art.html" >Поп-арт</a></li><li class="item-161"><a href="/eklektika.html" >Эклектика</a></li><li class="item-162"><a href="/modernn.html" >Модерн</a></li></ul>
        </div>
            <div class="moduletable">
                            <div class=" modtit">По производителю</div>
                        <ul class="nav menu">
<li class="item-156"><a href="/buldoors.html" >Бульдорс</a></li></ul>
        </div>
    </div>            <div id="right">
                <div class="right_top">     <div class="moduletable">
                            <div class=" modtit1">Мы предоставляем комплекс услуг</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#left').on('click', function(){
    $('.moduletable').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
    $('#main-content').animate({
        'margin-left' : $('#main-content').css('margin-left') == '0px' ? '210px' : '0px'
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```js
jQuery('#left .moduletable').on('click', function(){
   jQuery(this).find('ul.nav').slideToggle( "slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left">
 <div class="moduletable">
  <div class=" modtit">По материалу</div>
  <ul class="nav menu">
   <li class="item-118"><a href="/metallicheskie-dveri.html" >Металлические двери</a></li>
   <li class="item-119"><a href="/derevyannye-dveri.html" >Клееный брус</a></li>
   <li class="item-121"><a href="/plastikovye-dveri.html" >Пластиковые двери</a></li>
   <li class="item-122"><a href="/shponirovannye-dveri.html" >Шпонированные двери</a></li>
   <li class="item-157"><a href="/massiv-drevesiny.html" >Массив древесины</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="moduletable">
  <div class=" modtit">Фурнитура</div>
  <ul class="nav menu">
   <li class="item-163"><a href="/catalog-ruchek.html" >Каталог дверных ручек</a></li>
   <li class="item-164"><a href="/zamki.html" >Замки и защелки</a></li>
   <li class="item-165"><a href="/koroba.html" >Наличники и короба</a></li>
   <li class="item-166"><a href="/arki.html" >Арки</a></li>
   <li class="item-167"><a href="/lestnitsy.html" >Лестницы</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="moduletable diz">
  <div class=" modtit">По дизайну</div>
  <ul class="nav menu">
   <li class="item-136"><a href="/barokko.html" >Барокко</a></li>
   <li class="item-137"><a href="/klassika.html" >Классика</a></li>
   <li class="item-158"><a href="/ampir.html" >Ампир</a></li>
   <li class="item-159"><a href="/minimalizm.html" >Минимализм</a></li>
   <li class="item-160"><a href="/pop-art.html" >Поп-арт</a></li>
   <li class="item-161"><a href="/eklektika.html" >Эклектика</a></li>
   <li class="item-162"><a href="/modernn.html" >Модерн</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="moduletable">
  <div class=" modtit">По производителю</div>
  <ul class="nav menu">
   <li class="item-156"><a href="/buldoors.html" >Бульдорс</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="right">
<div class="right_top">
<div class="moduletable">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This can be one of the option.

Comment: what another you want ? 
You were looking for the same, Right ?